# how to build a json return in php?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, json

i have a function that looks like this.

```
function startChatSession($items) {


    foreach ($test as $chatbox => $void) {
            $items .= $this->chatBoxSession($chatbox);
        }

    if ($items != '') {
        $items = substr($items, 0, -1);
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    ?>
    {
        "username": "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>",
       "items": [
            <?php echo $items;?>
        ]
    }

    <?php
    exit(0);
}
```

i am interested in the second part of this function. I would like to translate it to sometihng like:

```
    echo json_encode(array(
            'username'=>$_SESSION['username'], 
            'items'=>$items
        )); 

    exit;
```

this kind of works, but not quite.

the response should look like:

```
{
    "username": "johndoe",
    "items": [{
        "s": "1",
        "f": "janedoe",
        "m": "dqwdqwd"
    }, {
        "s": "1",
        "f": "janedoe",
        "m": "sdfwsdfgdfwfwe"
    }, {
        "s": "1",
        "f": "janedoe",
        "m": "werwefgwefwefwefweg"
    }]
}
```

in my case it looks like:

```
{
    "username": "johndoe",
    "items": "\t\t\t\t\t   {\r\n\t\t\t\"s\": \"1\",\r\n\t\t\t\"f\": \"babydoe\",\r\n\t\t\t\"m\": \"test\"\r\n\t   },\t\t\t\t\t   {\r\n\t\t\t\"s\": \"1\",\r\n\t\t\t\"f\": \"\",\r\n\t\t\t\"m\": \"\"\r\n\t   }"
}
```

any ideas?

thanks

edit:

if i dump the `$items` i the something like:

```
{
    s: 1,
    f: babydoe,
    m:  test
}, {
    s: 1,
    f: babydoe,
    m:  test
}, {
    s:1,
    f: babydoe,
    m:  test
}, {
    s: 1,
    f: babydoe,
    m:  test
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are pretty-printing `$items`. If you are messing around with `$items` before calling `json_encode` then nothing can be done

Comment: what is the reason you are deleting 1 character of the $items with substr? If we can skip or adjust that part, we can just return an array and things will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    echo json_encode(array(
        'username'=>$_SESSION['username'], 
        'items'=>array($items)
    ));
```

You need a multi level array.

See [codepad](http://codepad.org/ZCD2aLlP) for example.

Comment: nope. it looks like the `$items` is not an array. see my post edit please

Comment: It looks like a array to me, so my code should work. Try putting `$items = array($items);` before my code.

Comment: yes. it seems to work but i still get those escapes `\t\t\t\t\t   {\r\n\t\t\t\"s\": \"1\",\r\n\t\t\t\"f\":......` any ideas there?

Comment: Maybe items is already json encoded, so you're encoding it double. Try $items = array(json_decode($items));

Comment: it comes back null `"items":[null]`

Comment: How did you dump $items ? which exact code? It looks like JSON but it is not correct

Comment: i used zend_debug::dump();, similar with var_dump().

Comment: Try echo is_array($items) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array'; to confirm if it really is an array.. strange

Comment: i get not an Array. looks like is just a string. hold on, i found how $items is done. i add it to my post

Answer (score 1):

Your $items array should look like this:

```
<?php
$items = array(
  0 => array('s'=>1, 'f'=>'janedoe', 'm'=>'dqwdqwd'),
  1 => array('s'=>1, 'f'=>'janedoe', 'm'=>'sdfwsdfgdfwfwe'),
  2 => array('s'=>1, 'f'=>'janedoe', 'm'=>'werwefgwefwefwefweg')
);

echo json_encode(array(
        'username'=>$_SESSION['username'], 
        'items'=>$items
    ));
?>
```

http://codepad.org/mZk4hsKq

Comment: OK, so $items is an json string. `json_encode` is trying to take an array and create a json string from that - you need to decode the `$items` string first.

Comment: $items is NOT valid JSON. It is missing the quotes and stuff. It looks like it but is is not

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$items = substr($items, 0, -1);
```

To:

```
foreach($items as $index => $d){
$items[$index] = substr($d, 0, -1);
}
```